# error ejecutar npx react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode, macos, programación-móvil

Son mi ultima opción! ya probé muchas cosas!!!
Soy nuevo en iOs, me compre una macbook 2013 y necesito buildear un repo de github de react-native en iOs, busque que tenía que instalar, instale lo que me decían y cuando quiero ejecutar el codigo me da este error

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening ristoUserApp.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ristoUserApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ristoUserApp -destination id=8E3F8049-D396-42DE-AC07-4AF830140899

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

Create build description
Build description signature: 328fe01f45ed45646dd14268fcfd8fd2
Build description path: /Users/micaylucas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ristoUserApp-bhhkvvvuvuirshbrygmlxgnmtakg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/328fe01f45ed45646dd14268fcfd8fd2-desc.xcbuild

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

Estuve leyendo que tenía que actualizar xCode pero no puedo porque no es compatible con mi version de MacOS. (11.7.5) de xCode me descargue la 13.2.1.

Tambien leí que tenía que hacer esto pero no termino de entender.

1. run cd ios
2. run pod install
3. cd ...
4. delete build folder
5. run react-native run-ios

La verdad es que encontre miles de errores y posible soluciones, estoy algo perdido ya que probé muchas cosas y no funcionan.
Muchas gracias por ayudarme !!!